# detect conflicts after git-svn rebase

Tags: git, automation, git-svn, lazy-evaluation, git-rebase

I'm using so many git-svn repositories (at the same time) that it's becoming a chore to update them all. I'd like to write a script that automates this, so I can just run it every morning while I fetch a coffee.

Basically my workflow is like this

```
cd ~/module1
git svn fetch
git checkout master
git svn rebase

git checkout topicbranch
git svn rebase

cd ~/module2
git svn fetch
git checkout master
git svn rebase
```

I've already automated the `git svn fetch` part, which can be safely done anytime. But it's not so safe to do git svn rebase automatically as there might be conflicts.

How can a script figure out if there was a conflict after a rebase? Then I could run git rebase --abort, and write a line to a log file so I can review the failures when I get back with my coffee :)

Answer (score 3):

After doing "git svn fetch", you can use a *merge* instead of a *rebase* to get the latest svn stuff into your local branch.  If the merge is successful, you'll know because there are no conflicts (which you can find with tools like git ls-files).  If the merge *doesn't* work, you haven't mangled anything and can just ignore those toplevel changes to your work tree.

Then do a rebase as a last step before committing (if you want; it's not strictly needed) and you can handle the error-prone rebasing interactively only once.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from `git-svn`, `git-rebase`, and `git-sh-setup` git will exit with an exit code of `1` if the rebase can not be performed due to conflicts.

Comment: That seems right, although it will also return 1 if the rebase cannot be performed because e.g. there are uncommitted changes in the working copy. Should I just run git rebase --abort anyway?

Comment: Well, if a rebase can not be performed without interaction you don’t really have a choice when it’s being run automated, do you?